# Suppress prompt confirmation for Import-Module PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, import-module

I am trying to import akamaipowershell powershell module using script while importing it prompts for install nuget package but I want to skip that prompt same as NO.

`Import-Module ./akamaipowershell -Force`

I have tried using the Force parameter but still getting prompt and when I am trying to use `-Confirm:$False` getting invalid parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guilty for this is the checking for a module update when import it (line 28 `Find-Module AkamaiPowerShell` of the .psm1 file).

As you can see it on the previous line, you can set an environment variable to block this behaviour before importing the module :

```
$env:AkamaiPowerShellDisableUpdateCheck = $true
Import-Module ./akamaipowershell
```

This will not ask for installing the nuget package.